# extending objects at run-time via categories?

Tags: objective-c

> Objective-C’s objects are pretty flexible when compared to similar languages like C++ and can be extended at runtime via Categories or through runtime functions.

Any idea what this sentence means? I am relatively new to Objective-C

Comment: And have you searched the internet for "Objective-C categories"?

Answer (score 1):

While technically true, it may be confusing to the reader to call category extension "at runtime." As Justin Meiners explains, categories allow you to add additional methods to an existing class without requiring access to the existing class's source code. The use of categories is fairly common in Objective-C, though there are some dangers. If two different categories add the same method to the same class, then the behavior is undefined. Since you cannot know whether some other part of the system (perhaps even a system library) adds a category method, you typically must add a prefix to prevent collisions (for example rather than `swappedString`, a better name would likely be something like `rnc_swappedString` if this were part of `RNCryptor` for instance.)

As I said, it is technically true that categories are added at runtime, but from the programmer's point of view, categories are written as though just part of the class, so most people think of them as being a compile-time choice. It is very rare to decide at runtime whether to add a category method or not.

As a beginner, you should be aware of categories, but slow to create new ones. Creating categories is a somewhat intermediate-level skill. It's not something to avoid, but not something you'll use every day. It's very easy to overuse them. See Justin's link for more information.

On the other hand, "runtime functions" really do add new functionality to existing classes or even specific objects at runtime, and are completely under the control of code. You can, at runtime, modify a class such that it responds to a method it didn't previously respond to. You can even generate entirely new classes at runtime that did not exist when the program was compiled, and you can change the class of existing objects. (This is exactly how Key-Value Observation is implemented.)

Modifying classes and objects using the runtime is an advanced skill. You should not even consider using these techniques in production code until you have significant experience. And when you have that experience, it will tell you that you very seldom what to do this anyway. You will know the runtime functions because they are C-based, with names like `method_exchangeImplmentations`. You won't mistake them for normal ObjC (and you generally have to import `objc/runtime.h` to get to them.)

There is a middle-ground that bleeds into runtime manipulation called message forwarding and dynamic message resolution. This is often used for proxy objects, and is implemented with `-forwardingTargetForSelector`, `+resolveInstanceMethod`, and some similar methods. These are tools that allow classes to modify *themselves* at runtime, and is much less dangerous than modifying other classes (i.e. "swizzling").

It's also important to consider how all of this translates to Swift. In general, Swift has discouraged and restricted the use of runtime class manipulation, but it embraces (and improves) category-like extensions. By the time you're experienced enough to dig into the runtime, you will likely find it an even more obscure skill than it is today. But you will use extensions (Swift's version of categories) in every program.

Answer (score 0):

A category allows you to add functionality to an existing class that you do not have access to source code for (System frameworks, 3rd party APIs etc). This functionality is possible by adding methods to a class at runtime.

For example lets say I wanted to add a method to `NSString` that swapped uppercase and lowercase letters called `-swappedString`. In static languages (such as C++), extending classes like this is more difficult. I would have to create a subclass of `NSString` (or a helper function). While my own code could take advantage of my subclass, any instance created in a library would not use my subclass and would not have my method.

Using categories I can extend any class, such as adding a `-swappedString` method and use it on any instance of the class, such as`NSString` transparently `[anyString swappedString];`.

You can learn more details from [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)